# How to convert curl response xml to plain/csv/xls for a total count

Tags: bash, curl, xml

I have a script that send sms for a trigger using a sms gateway. The command to send sms used is curl as below:

```
curl 'http://www.example.com/push/server.php?user=******&pass=*******&sid=******&sms=Test+SMS+Check&msisdn=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&csmsid=123456789'
```

It get reply as an xml format as below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><REPLY><PARAMETER>OK</PARAMETER><LOGIN>SUCCESSFULL</LOGIN><PUSHAPI>ACTIVE</PUSHAPI><STAKEHOLDERID>OK</STAKEHOLDERID><PERMITTED>OK</PERMITTED><SMSINFO><MSISDN>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</MSISDN><SMSTEXT>Test+SMS+Check</SMSTEXT><CSMSID>123456789</CSMSID><REFERENCEID>2020050321383271896124009</REFERENCEID></SMSINFO></REPLY>
```

Now I want to track the count and list of sms sent for billing issue. That's why I need to convert the output xml response to either a text file or a csv or a xlx file that will append each response to a line and count total number of sent sms.

Comment: Just appending that single line of XML to a text file would allow you to count the number of lines in the file with `wc -l` to get the number of SMS' sent. Let me know if it needs to be more sophisticated than that.

Comment: Yes, that will work but if I want to keep record of those responses in a human readable format then I might need a csv type format.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, but try this...

your_command | tee -a  logfile

this will run your command and append to a file called "logfile",
you can then look in the logfile,  do  wc -l against it, etc.

Comment: tnx for your response, Yes, that will work but if I want to keep record of those responses in a human readable format then I might need a csv type format.